# Search for node to reference

Tags: nodes

I have a content type that has a reference field to another content type, call it "associated".

When editing the content, I'd like the user to be able to search for the "associated" entity to link to, for example using a view with a exposed filter.

Is there any combination of modules that will allow me to do this?

So i'm basically after a select widget that bring up a popup or something similar.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I know of, is the [relation](http://drupal.org/project/references) and [relation select](http://drupal.org/project/relation_select) module combo. Relation select hasn't seen any development for quite a while, but you might be able to get where you want. It allows you to setup a view with exposed filters can be be used to selecting the node you want to reference.

This is Drupal 7 only.

Comment: Hi, yes this should be close to what I need, thank you.